# Box having text I wrote

Tags: php, javascript

I need some script to contain same content as a  while im writting.

So for example:

I write Page 1 in my browser.

And then some box, which should not be editable from the browser - contains the same "page 1" just edited a: "-" whenever I'm writting a Space.

Actually a bit like on stackoverflow - just where it's adding "-" everytime I write a Space.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This function will take pretty much whatever you throw at it (not unicode though) and turn it into something that is URL safe:

```
function url_from_text($string) {
    $string = preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z0-9-]/', ' ', $string);
    $string = preg_replace('/ +/', ' ', $string);
    $string = trim($string);
    $string = str_replace(' ', '-', $string);
    $string = preg_replace('/-+/', '-', $string);
    $string = strtolower($string);

    return $string;
}
```

Your database could then have two fields, 'title' and 'slug', where 'slug' is the title converted with the function above.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to produce a URL from a title, you could just use https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php to replace spaces with dashes.

Comment: I know. But then I have a problem when I want to use the title as content <h1></h1> tag too. You know, I don't want a header to be Page-1

Comment: @Kolind You have to store "Page 1" and "Page-1" into two differente fields.

Comment: @seriousdev Hm, so I should make a field in my Database, with the URL made title and one for the title to show?

Comment: @seriousdev And how would you make the str_replace(); ? I'm new to the str_replace(); function.

Comment: There were examples on the page, hence I didnt feel the need to include further